# How can I run fewer CircleCI jobs with my Github webhook configuration?

Tags: github, circleci

The default Github CircleCI webhook integration runs our tests for every push to github. We probably really only care about running our CCI tests for 1/50th of these pushes. But since we pay for every run on CCI, this is costing us a lot more money than we need to be spending.

How can I re-configure the webhook to run less often? Is there a way to run it manually or have some kind of keyword detection in the "last" commit message?

What's a good solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CircleCI has two built-in options.

1. You can use the string `[skip ci]` in a commit message and CircleCI won't build it.
2. In Project Settings, you can turn on a setting that will only build PRs. With this feature on, regular commits before a PR is open will not run.

Keep in mind, just some advice, I get the desire to save money, but reducing how often you test reduces the value received from CI. Just keep that in mind.

Comment: Glad to see CircleCi has folks monitoring SO questions! I also found the setting that will cancel previously running jobs if a new push happens before a previous one has finished. I assume the `[skip ci]` needs to include the brackets?

Comment: Correct. This is actually a common string you can use across many CI providers in order to not build on CI.